# Invoke Application (Custom application which has arguments) on Remote System using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

I have one custom application which install or other system & I want to call that from this system using WMI C# without any batch file.

Moreover that application has command arguments to run. So, can anyone guide me what I suppose to code ?

I already tried few things which I am pasting here (code snippet) for your reference which works fine in case of Notepad.exe or Calc.exe to run. 
In fact, It also works for me in my custom application without arguments but not with arguments. When I passed with arguments it start & kill after 2 seconds. Which means it doesn't pass arguments in well/ proper format.

```
private static uint CreateProcess(ManagementScope connectionScope, string exeWithPathAndArguments)
    {
        try
        {
            var objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementPath processPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");

            using (var processTask = new ManagementClass(connectionScope, processPath, objectGetOptions))
            {
                using (var methodInParams = processTask.GetMethodParameters("Create"))
                {
                    methodInParams["CommandLine"] = exeWithPathAndArguments;
                    using (var methodOutParams = processTask.InvokeMethod("Create", methodInParams, null))
                    {
                        var err = (uint)methodOutParams["returnValue"];
                        if (err != 0)
                        {
                            var info = "see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx";
                            switch (err)
                            {
                                case 2: info = "Access Denied"; break;
                                case 3: info = "Insufficient Privilege"; break;
                                case 8: info = "Unknown failure"; break;
                                case 9: info = "Path Not Found"; break;
                                case 21: info = "Invalid Parameter"; break;
                                default: info = "Unknown(Code)"; break;
                            }

                            var msg = "Failed to Start the Process, error = " + methodOutParams["returnValue"] + " (" + info + ")";
                            throw new Exception(msg);
                        }

                        return (uint)methodOutParams["processId"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I already aware with PSExec but I don't want to use that. Same time I don't want to use Batch File to run my command. Just want to use direct command passing way to run the application.
My Application location is not in PATH Directory. so, obviously I need to supply a full path like...

CreateProcess(connectionScope, exeWithPathAndArguments.Trim());
where exeWithPathAndArguments would be "/"C:\Program files (x86)\Company\Application Folder\app.exe/" -argsName argvalue"

Answer (score 0):

Add `methodInParams["CurrentDirectory"] = wheretostartapp;` and delete `-argsName`

So your `exeWithPathAndArguments` will be:

`\"C:\\\\Program files (x86)\\\\Company\\\\Application Folder\\\\app.exe\" argvalue`